# Calculate the quarterly growth rate

Tags: r

I tried to calculate the quarterly growth rate in sales for different stores. However, I group by my data several times until it became the following status:

How can I generate the growth rate table based on this equation: (Q3-Q2)/Q2?

The code I programmed so far is as follows. Thank you.

| Store | Quarter | Weekly_Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Q2 | 60428109 |
| 1 | Q3 | 20253948 |
| 2 | Q2 | 74356864 |
| 2 | Q3 | 24303355 |
| 3 | Q2 | 15459190 |
| 3 | Q3 | 5298005 |
| 4 | Q2 | 79302989 |
| 4 | Q3 | 27796792 |
| 5 | Q2 | 12523263 |
| 5 | Q3 | 4163791 |

```r
library("dplyr")
library("lubridate")
Walmart_data_set <- read.csv("Walmart_Store_sales.csv")

Walmart_data_set$Date <- as.Date(Walmart_data_set$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")
Walmart_data_set["Month"] <- month(Walmart_data_set$Date)
Walmart_data_set["Quarter"] <- quarters(Walmart_data_set$Date)
Walmart_data_set["Year"] <- format(Walmart_data_set$Date, format ="%Y")


Q23_2012_Sales<- filter(Walmart_data_set, Year == "2012" & Quarter == "Q3" | Quarter == "Q2")
Sales_Store_quarter = Q23_2012_Sales %>% group_by(Store, Quarter)  %>%
  summarise(Weekly_Sales = sum(Weekly_Sales),
            .groups = 'drop')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(Store, Quarter) %>% 
  group_by(Store) %>% 
  mutate(growth = (Weekly_Sales - lag(Weekly_Sales))/lag(Weekly_Sales))
```

Output:

```
   Store Quarter Weekly_Sales growth
   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1 Q2          60428109 NA    
 2     1 Q3          20253948 -0.665
 3     2 Q2          74356864 NA    
 4     2 Q3          24303355 -0.673
 5     3 Q2          15459190 NA    
 6     3 Q3           5298005 -0.657
 7     4 Q2          79302989 NA    
 8     4 Q3          27796792 -0.649
 9     5 Q2          12523263 NA    
10     5 Q3           4163791 -0.668
```

Comment: Thank you, bro. The result is successfully performed. Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 0):

Don't group by `Quarter`.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  arrange(Store, Quarter) %>%
  group_by(Store) %>%
  mutate(Growth = c(NA, diff(Weekly_Sales)) / dplyr::lag(Weekly_Sales)) %>%
  ungroup()
# . + > 
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#    Store Quarter Weekly_Sales Growth
#    <int> <chr>          <int>  <dbl>
#  1     1 Q2          60428109 NA    
#  2     1 Q3          20253948 -0.665
#  3     2 Q2          74356864 NA    
#  4     2 Q3          24303355 -0.673
#  5     3 Q2          15459190 NA    
#  6     3 Q3           5298005 -0.657
#  7     4 Q2          79302989 NA    
#  8     4 Q3          27796792 -0.649
#  9     5 Q2          12523263 NA    
# 10     5 Q3           4163791 -0.668
```

This method assumes that you always have a `Q2` for each `Q3`. (The converse would be you have more history in your data, with some stores perhaps gapping a quarter or two.)

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Store = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), Quarter = c("Q2", "Q3", "Q2", "Q3", "Q2", "Q3", "Q2", "Q3", "Q2", "Q3"), Weekly_Sales = c(60428109L, 20253948L, 74356864L, 24303355L, 15459190L, 5298005L, 79302989L, 27796792L, 12523263L, 4163791L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: looks like you and I have the same code, but different results. Am I missing something?  I may be mistaken of course, but it appears that your output doesn't quite match what the code actually does?

Comment: Thank you, r2evans. I tried to re-check the result of number, it seems the equation is a little different from the condition: (Q3-Q2)/Q2...

Comment: @langtang ... not missing something, I didn't hand-calculate the numbers and OP never included expected output, so goofed. I don't have `dplyr` loaded late-enough, so `lag` was `base::lag`. I really wish `dplyr` and company had not overloaded such *fundamental base functions*, it makes so many bugs perfectly invisible.

Comment: @LeonSiKA: yes, and `Q3-Q2` is the same as `diff(WeeklySales)`, I believe. The reason for the different output is that my `dplyr` was loaded out-of-order, so `lag` was the wrong one ... corrected using the real `dplyr::lag`, I get the same output now. (FYI, this could have been caught earlier if, in your question, you had included hand-calculated ***expected values***. With some things it seems unnecessary (and this should have been clearer to me, certainly), but it ensures you and the answerers are on the same page. Glad you got the help you needed!

Comment: Thank you, @r2evans, your answer taught me a lot~. I got deeper learning about the dplyr function. Thanks bro~